# How to get a hyperlink in an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, flash, xsd

I want to set hyperlink in the image in XML file.

Here is my code of XML file:

```
<logos>
<logo id="1" name="Abc" path="abc.jpg" x="23" y="4" height="10" width="60"/>
<logo id="2" name="Xya" path="xyz.jpg" x="50" y="`4" height="20" width="40"/>
</logos>
```

I want to set hyperlink in this image.

Comment: Need more details.. what is this XML for? is it consumed by a Webservice? Is this your own format? You are leaving crucial details out!

Comment: I want to display images in Flash using this XML file. This is my own formate where x and y stands for position.

Comment: Well make sure your flash swf is capable of reading whatever format you have defined. I don't see an issue here.

Comment: This old question can be closed as "unclear".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is a **generic** data format. It doesn't have any hyperlink capabilities. A specific XML application *can* (XHTML, for example, has the `a` element).

If the XML application you are using doesn't include anything to describe hyperlinks, then you need to change it, possibly by importing something from another namespace (such as [XLink](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink11/)).

The software that consumes the application will almost certainly have to be updated to add support for the change you make to the language.

Comment: It's also possible to add a specific attribute, like link="http://foo.comm/myimage.png". The application should interpret this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML file, you need to tell it to ignore tags that are intended as html
tags and not tags of the xml structure by enclosing the html using

```
<![CDATA[ your html ]]>

<urlLink><![CDATA[ <a href="...whatever">Click Here</a> ]]></urlLink>
```

Comment: I tried it but not working dear. can you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would set an attribute in the  node for link_out like:

```
<logo link_out=""...
```

Or create a child element to the Logo node if multiple links will ever be in use.

Really hard to understand your need for this.

Comment: I think you forgot your example, Veign. `<logo id="1" name="Abc" path="abc.jpg" x="23" y="4" height="10" width="60" url="http://www.example.com/"/>`

Comment: I don't follow.  Forgot my example?  I was just posting the relevant part of the node.

Answer (score 1):

what XML structure are you following? If you aren't following one, what is stopping you from doing something like:

```
<logos>
   <logo>
     <image blah="">
     <link blah="">
   </logo>
</logos>
```

Hard to help you when there are a myriad of solutions, but we don't have all the details.